# Fiddler cpatured secure web service most of time but failed to pass information to HTTPS (looks like chop off of the request)

Tags: asp.net, fiddler, x509

I have a web application which use soap web service with x509 certificate.  I set

or  in my web.config, it captures the secure web service requests fine.  But we also call another domain (HTTPS web site) to pass information and it failed with either of these setttings in web.config (failed right away 500 error).   The fiddler captured the request but it misses lot of parameters that are supposed to pass to the HTTPs service.  Why would above setting chop off the request?  Anyone knows how to resolve this?  Thanks.

Junping

Comment: Why indeed. Sorry, unless you provide more information, your guess will be as good as anyone else's.

Comment: The issue here is that if I add proxy in web.config " bypassonlocal="True" proxyaddress="http://localhost:8888"  I could see the secure web service request but the request to another domain web service is not through.   If I don't add this proxy, then I don't see the secure web service request but am able to go to the other domain (not sure why as I thought the Fiddler is midman that just passes information intact betweeen).  Thanks.

Comment: For anyone to help, you'll need to provide much more information. A screenshot of Fiddler (or much better, a SAZ File saved using the Save button in Fiddler) might help a lot. If I had to guess, you didn't put the Fiddler root certificate in the *machine*'s Trusted Root certificate store, so you only see a `CONNECT` tunnel which is abandoned when your ASPX page sees Fiddler's certificate.